# How do I rename files found with the find command

Tags: bash, find, renaming

I have a series of music folders.  Some of the file names contain an underscore which I would like to get rid of.

With

```
find /Users/Chris/CDs -type f -name "*_*"
```

I find all of the files with underscores.
it appears that I can add `-execdir mv {}` to the command but do not know what to add from there.
I think `{}` provides the full path and file name as a string of the file with underscores but I do not know how to use something like `sed 's/_//g'` to remove the _ on the new file name.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find /Users/Chris/CDs -type f -name "*_*" -execdir bash -c 'mv -i -- "$1" "${1//_/}"' Mover  {} \;
```

How it works:

- `-execdir bash -c '...' Mover  {} \;`

  This starts up bash and tells it to run the command in the single quotes with `Mover` assigned to `$0` and the file name assigned to `$1`.
- `mv -i -- "$1" "${1//_/}"`

  This renames file `$1`.  This uses bash's parameter expansion feature, `${1//_/}`, to create the target name from `$1` by removing all underlines.

  The option `-i` tells `mv` to ask interactively before overwriting a file.

  The option `--` tells `mv` that there are no more options.  This is needed so that files whose names begin with `-` will be processed correctly.

#### Example

Let's start with a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
1_2_3_4  a_b  c_d
```

Next we run our command:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*_*" -execdir bash -c 'mv -i -- "$1" "${1//_}"' Mover  {} \;
```

After the command completes, the files are:

```
$ ls
1234  ab  cd
```

#### The purpose of `$0`

Observe this command where we have added an error:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*_*" -execdir bash -c 'foobar -i -- "$1" "${1//_}"' Mover  {} \;
Mover: foobar: command not found
```

Note that `Mover` appears at the beginning of the error message.  This signals that the error comes from within the `bash -c` command.

If we replace `Mover` with `-`, we would see:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*_*" -execdir bash -c 'foobar -i -- "$1" "${1//_}"' -  {} \;
-: foobar: command not found
```

When running a single command in a terminal, the source of the error may still be obvious anyway. If this `find` command were buried inside a long script, however, the use of a more descriptive `$0`, like `Mover` or whatever, could be a big help.

Comment: Probably want to use `mv -i` to avoid inadvertently overwriting any files.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Very good.  I should have remembered that.  Thank you.  Answer updated with `-i`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I follow everything except Mover {}.

Comment: @ChrisH `Mover` is assigned to `$0` and the file name, `{}`, is assigned to `$1`.  `$0` does nothing unless the `mv` command generates an error in which case the shell would report the error as being in the script `Mover`.  So, choosing a descriptive name for `$0` just makes error messages, if there were any, more readable.  You can use any name you want for this.  People who don't care about informative error messages often just use `-` for `$0` .

Comment: @ChrisH I just added to the end of the answer an example of how `Mover` is used.

Comment: I am new to bash but am amazed at its power.  Thank you for your assistance, particularly the in depth explanation.