# Not able to replace all filenames in directory containing a substring with another substring

Tags: bash

```
FROM=$1
TO=$2
find . -name '*'$FROM'*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/$FROM/$TO}"' -- {} \;
```

`find . -name '*'$FROM'*' -type f` part is finding files correctly, but `mv` part doesn't seem to work

Comment: `-exec bash -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1/$FROM/$TO}"' somename {} \;`  (otherwise your `$1` isn't provided as the filename `{}` is taken as `$0`) and your POSIX end-of-options `--` is in the wrong place.

Comment: what's `somename`?

Comment: `somename` is the equivalent of the program name (e.g. `$0`) for the invocation of `bash -c ...`. You can call it anything you like, but give it a name. If you don't, your substituted filename from `{}` is taken as `$0` not `$1` and your command fails.

Comment: Here is the link to a similar question [How do I rename files found with the find command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643041/how-do-i-rename-files-found-with-the-find-command)

Comment: In addition to that, unless `FROM` and `TO` were exported, they won't be set inside the bash invocation.